# What is meant by Type parameterization via erasure in java?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, jvm, bytecode

While reading About JVM.. I came across these lines

> The JVM knows nothing about type parameters. All type parameters are erased by the Java compiler and
>   replaced with the type Object. An array of parameter type T then becomes an array of Object in the context
>   of the JVM, which is why you can’t write expressions like new T[n].

Does this mean When i write

> Function(int a)

a is replaced with type object i.e with Integer Object ? 
or `int[10];`
becomes `Integer[10];`
If not so what is it meant to say?

Please explain it in Simple terminology.

Answer (score 3):

Type erasure refers only to [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html). A method such as `Function(int a)` won't be affected.

On the other hand, this code will:

```
public class Node<T> {

    private T data;
    private Node<T> next;

    public Node(T data, Node<T> next) }
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public T getData() { return data; }
    // ...
}
```

Will be replaced with this:

```
public class Node {

    private Object data;
    private Node next;

    public Node(Object data, Node next) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public Object getData() { return data; }
    // ...
}
```

(example taken from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html))

Answer (score 2):

> All type parameters are erased by the Java compiler and replaced with the type Object.

This passage talks specifically about type parameters in generic classes. So if you write a method that looks like this

```
public <T> void foo(T arg);
```

the type of `arg` in the generated method would be `java.lang.Object`. Non-generic methods remain unchanged.

> Does this mean When i write `function(int a)` a is replaced with type object i.e with Integer Object?

No, it does not, because the rule applies only to generic methods and methods of generic classes that use generic type parameters for their arguments or return types.

> So if my `List<>` is supposed to store `String` and if information about `String` is removed and converted into `Object`, how does JVM knows it is should accept `String` to store in the `List<>` and how does it check?

JVM does not know and does not check the type of objects that go into the list, because it does not have the relevant information. All type checking of generic type parameters is done at compile time. JVM know that the objects that get into the list at runtime are actually `String`s, because the compiler ensured that all type-safe code paths put strings into the list. The flip side of this is that you can trick the compiler into letting you place invalid objects into a list (say, `Integer`s into a list of `String`s) by type casting the list or by using its non-generic methods, but fooling the compiler takes deliberate action on your part.

For more information on *type erasure* see [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Comment: So would be the return type right ?

While some of the answer below has said About Collections(generic type)
List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();  the information about String is removed during the compilation process; the JVM won't know anything about it.

Can you explain me this ? 
So if my List is supposed to store String and If information about String is removed and converted into Object .. How does JVM knows it is should accept String to store in the List and how does it check. does it store this information somewhere as we can supply any type of object ?

Comment: @AnkurAnand Yes, this applies to return types as well. For generic type parameters used as parameters of other generic types (say, `T` in `List<T>`) the substitution is performed as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting it wrong:type erasure is related to the Java Generics.

If you write something like `List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();`, the information about `String` is removed during the compilation process; the JVM won't know anything about it.

Comment: So if my List is supposed to store String and If information about String is removed and converted into Object .. How does JVM knows it is should accept String to store in the List and how does it check. does it store this information somewhere as we can supply any type of object ?

Comment: @AnkurAnand These checks happen completely at compilation time. There it is ensured that the restrictions are obeyed.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Type parameters are the things in angle brackets.

```
List<Integer> list = new List<>();
```

`Integer` is the type parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Type erasure applies to the use of generics. There's definitely metadata in the class file to say whether or not a method/type is generic, and what the constraints are etc. But when generics are used, they're converted into compile-time checks and execution-time casts.